# Cannot access permission to microphone

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, permissions, microphone

I am trying to use the react-native-live-audio-stream library. However I get errors with the permission of the microphone.

I am following [this exact link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-live-audio-stream) on how to set it up.

This is my recorder component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import LiveAudioStream from 'react-native-live-audio-stream';

export default function Recorder() {
  const options = {
    sampleRate: 32000, // default is 44100 but 32000 is adequate for accurate voice recognition
    channels: 1, // 1 or 2, default 1
    bitsPerSample: 16, // 8 or 16, default 16
    audioSource: 6, // android only (see below)
  };
  LiveAudioStream.init(options);
  LiveAudioStream.on('data', (data) => {
    // base64-encoded audio data chunks
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onClick={LiveAudioStream.start()}>
        <Text>Start recording!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The error I get is:

```
startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
```

So I start investigating the permission thing... This is what I've got so far:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

By adding a request for the microphone like this:

```
const requestMicrophone = async () =>{
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
      new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
      REQUEST_MICROPHONE);
}
```

I get the error of:

```
[![ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String\[\]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
```

REQUEST_MICROPHONE][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0wQP.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0wQP.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT:
I fixed the error! The audio related things in the recorder needs to be put in a function which is called by starting the recording.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for taking permission in android:

```
import {PermissionsAndroid, Platform} from 'react-native';
.....
const requestMicrophone = async () => { //replace your function with this code.
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                try {
                  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    {
                      title: 'Permissions for record audio',
                      message: 'Give permission to your device to record audio',
                      buttonPositive: 'ok',
                    },
                  );
                  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    console.log('permission granted');
                  } else {
                    console.log('permission denied');
                    return;
                  }
                } catch (err) {
                  console.warn(err);
                  return;
                }
              }
        }
```

Comment: I still get the "startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord." error.

Comment: Don't use onClick event. Replace onClick with this:
onPress={()=>LiveAudioStream.start()}

Answer (score 0):

First you are using `onClick event` its react event not react native you should switch to `onPress event` also you are invoking `LiveAudioStream.start()` with each render by using `start()`

````
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity onClick={LiveAudioStream.start()}>
      <Text>Start recording!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>

//edited
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>LiveAudioStream.start}>
      <Text>Start recording!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>```
````